# Replacing emoji from a string

Tags: vb.net, surrogate-pairs

I am new to vb net. i am trying to process a string containing emoji but I cannot do it. my string looks like this: I want to replace  with  what i am doing is using string.remove and string.add but I am getting surrogate pair error.                           ​​

```
dim tStr as string =""
tStr=tStr.remove(5, 2)
tStr= tStr.insert(5,"")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you update your question with some more information what error you are exactly getting? :)

Comment: Use the mid command to replace the blue heart :- 

mid(tStr,3,1)=""

Comment: `tStr = tStr.Replace("", "")`. This question is getting too emotional.

Answer (score 0):

The index number used by the `Remove` and `Insert` methods are zero-based (the index of the first character is 0). To get the third emoji, you need to use 4 as the index instead of 5.

```
dim tStr as String =""
tStr=tStr.Remove(4, 2)
tStr= tStr.Insert(4,"")
```